# Are there any solutions for testing android applications other than using the default emulator?

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator, device

Is there any other solution for testing android applications other than using that slow emulator which comes with the android SDK?

I'm not interested in the testing service providers.

Comment: you can use your device phone to test your application, if u dont have it , than sorry , there is no other solution without using emulators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the obvious one, but use an actual, physical device. It's a good idea anyway if you plan on releasing it to the public.

But really - If you intend to make an app of any reasonable quality, you're going to need to test on a device. If you want to distribute it on a wide scale I would really opine that you should test it on several *different* devices, for that matter.

Comment: I would go past "a good idea anyway" straight on to "a requirement to make a quality app".

Comment: @CommonsWare: Yeah...I should really be more forceful with my phrasing, shouldn't I? :P

Comment: I'd change it to "physical **devices**" :)

Comment: @inazaruk: Ha, I was actually just adding "test on several different devices" as you noted that.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Android-x86 in VirtualBox. It runs fast, but there are a lot of restrictions.